# How to define order while Unmarshalling json into Empty interface?

Tags: json, api, go, unmarshalling

I have JSON response from an API. When i try to Unmarshal it into an Empty interface (var sample interface{} )the order becomes random and not according to the Query. Is there any way to maintain the same
order as the response?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Note that JSON objects (the {...} things) *are* unordered as are maps in Go, so the question as is doesn't make much sense as there *is* no order to preserve.

Also note that JSON arrays (the [...] things) *are* *orderer* and their order *will* be preserved when unmarshaling to a slice.